How can I properly harden my system against some basic exploits like modifications of .bashrc?
I recently read a section on bashrc in the ubuntuusers wiki, in which a possible attack vector for privilege escalation is pointed out. Attackers, or malicious programs, could modify the bashrc or bash_aliases to intercept sudo. The suggested solution is to either set the immutable flag to bashrc or not to work with an account that is allowed to use sudo and su. I had also considered that you could simply delete the bashrc, which would use the gloable configuration in /etc as a fallback, which only root is allowed to change. In such a case, however, the file could simply be recreated by a malicious program without me noticing.
In my case I am specifically concerned about such issues, not because I am paranoid, but because I regularly download Python packages for software development from PyPI, for example, which could potentially be contaminated and whose developers I have to trust completely (sometimes such packages also deliver binary blobs). The same applies to NPM and AUR, for example. And past experience has shown that supply chain attacks are definitely a relevant issue. However, I have never thought of such an attack on bashrc -- but it makes sense to me that it is possible and that the use of su and sudo in our current context should perhaps also be questioned...
But this leads me to my questions:

Are there other such completely avoidable attack vectors that are already preset in some distributions thanks to presets?
How can I reasonably harden my system without having to go to excessive lengths, for example with virtualization solutions?


Usually you cannot protect the system against yourself if you're this system super user. Whatever you do, e.g. sudo chmod 700, or sudo chattr, the bad actor can undo. You think using sudo is safe since it doesn't allow to e.g. LD_PRELOAD and similar tricks, but what about the hacker overriding sudo for you within your current shell? It could be a bash function or an alias.
Either use full virtualization, light virtualization (e.g. docker) or a separate user account that you can consider being compromised for all intents and purposes. The latter is my preferred option but it's not without its caveats, for instance if your system is not up to date or has unknown/yet to be disclosed 0-day vulnerabilities, that extra user account may hack your system, so full virtualization is a better option.
Also, if you're a web developer, they normally have access to some remote hosting which you could use for development. That's an even safer option, since it's a completely remote system.

It might be worth noting though, if sudo can be "exploited" in unprivileged operations (e.g. because it's passwordless), then a separate user account may not help much (at least not when the attack is so "smart" that it would try to e.g. contaminate every $HOME under /home with a little shell loop). And obviously it's not gonna help either if the operations themselves are already run as root.

Your ~/.bashrc file should (at the very least) have permissions like this:
-rw-r--r-- 1 kaz kaz 886 Mar 25 20:59 /home/kaz/.bashrc

If there is anything in it you don't want others to read, like some hard-coded password to something, then -rw------.
Permissions protect a non-root user from doing anything with your .bashrc.
The German-language article you are linking to is completely silly to be suggesting the chattr +i solution, while completely glossing over regular Unix permissions.
As a Unix user on a multi-user system, you should ensure that you have a umask correctly set up so that any new files you create deny write permission to others. Somewhere in your start-up environment do this:
umask 022

or more strictly
umask 066

The umask is a kernel-level variable associated with your processes, inherited by child processes, which specifies what permissions are removed from newly created files.  A umask 022 ensures that when you create a new file, it will not be writable to the group or others, while 066 will ensure that it will not be readable, either.
You can type umask with no arguments to see what your umask is now.
Usually, systems have a sensible umask value, which is why you rarely hear about someone being attacked via a world-writable .bashrc, even if they created the file from scratch themselves.
Remember, if some blog or other article gives a weird opinion unheard elsewhere about something extremely basic, it's probably just that: their own weird opinion. If chattr +i ~/.bashrc were necessary, everyone would be doing it. It would be in every FAQ, and the account creation scripts in every distro would be doing it (so that users would have to do chattr -i to edit the file). It's vanishingly improbable that the entire GNU/Linux and Unix world is ignorant of some basic file security problem that the author of some article claims to have hit upon.
chattr +i exists for a reason. Root can apply that permission to a root-owned file. That file will then be protected from accidental modification by root. (File operations ignore regular permissions if the caller is effectively root; root can overwrite a write-protected file.)
Furthermore, some operating systems have a heightened security mode in which the attribute changes are disabled, even to root. So that is to say, you can make files immutable with chattr -i and then boot into (or otherwise switch the entire operating system into) this security mode, such that even if someone gains unauthorized root access to that system, they cannot modify those files. In Linux, the CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability controls this.

chattr +i can have a point for operation that isn't supposed / needed to run as root, such as "user-specific" pip / npm install (certainly that is assuming sudo is not passwordless). On the contrary, permissions won't help in protecting the file from "malicious attack" (given that the attack can call chmod without any privilege). Besides, usually $HOME of regular users are 0700 anyway. The permissions of the stuff inside don't matter much with this regard.
